# Disable RMI Dynamic code downloading (using codebase) on Applet - Performance issue

Tags: java, performance, swing, applet, rmi

We are having a performance issue when loading our Swing application under an applet container.

The Swing client communicates with JBoss server using RMI protocol.
When comparing our webstart application VS the new Applet container , its seems that the 
Object marshaling taking much more time in the applet.

The ObjectInputStream -> writeExternal (using the JBoss Client RMI infra ) taking too much time to complete , 3-5x times then the webstart
In our ENV we have full deployment that sync all JARS between the server and the client (applet or webstart) so we don't need to load them remotely
The applet tag look like this:

archive="[contain list of 100 JARS -> about 200 MB]" 
codebase="http://[remoteApacheServer]/USERTEST:85600"

List item

List of params ...

When checked that on the applet bootstrap the Applet loaded all the JARS from the server
But checking with sniffer we saw that every time we marshaled a new Class the applet class loader didn't used the Local version and send another request to remoteApacheServer looking for the specific class.

We found out the solution for it: using applet parameter :
param name="codebase_lookup" value="false

also we saw that loading the JARS locally - setting local nodejs HTTP that will serve the JRAS and set the codebase to use this temp server also boostup the peformance .

even just create nodejs server that just proxying the request backto the original remoteApacheServer helped .

but still the performance is still not good :-(

we saw in the sniffer that the client sending a reqest every time with the applet codebase and the full list of archive (all 100 JARS) and we saw the RMI has a feature
(Dynamic code downloading using Java™ RMI)  that the Server can Marshell an Object even if its not exists in its local CLASSPATH.

see RMI setttings [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html)

Do you know any why to disable it - i think its can help use solving the performance issue.

maybe using the java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly ?

Comment: Wait, you have a webstart version and you chose to replace it with an Applet? Do you really need the Applet? Also, how are you serializing your Object(s)?

Comment: Most people would regard going from JWS to an Applet as a retrograde step. The simple answer to this problem is "don't".

Comment: The reason is because we need fully integration between are new web based (HTML5 + Angular) application and the old Java swing. the only way to do so is using applet tag.

Comment: The serilaztion is peformed by jboss serializtion (RMI) . old version of the jboss-all-client jar

Comment: after testing the  java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly flag its has no effect on the performance.

Comment: Also , sniffing the RMI requests we see that the client sending marshelling request with the applet codebase and the full list of archive (all 100 JARS)

Comment: EJP- we must use the applet in order to use js <-> applet communication .